# Why `xargs head` print filename?

Tags: linux, shell, xargs

Given two files, 
`a.txt` content is: `A1`, `b.txt` content is: `B1`

While execute `printf "a.txt\nb.txt" | xargs head -1`,

I hope it output

```
A1
B1
```

but it output

```
==> a.txt <==
A1

==> b.txt <==
B1
```

Why it output filename?
and how to disable the output of filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`head` is being executed with more than one argument. This causes the file names to be output. From the [head man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head):

> With more than one FILE, precede each with a header giving the file
>   name.

The header can be suppressed with the `--quiet` option:

```
printf "a.txt\nb.txt" | xargs head -1 --quiet
```